# calculate $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I have been stuck on the following practice problem for some time now and I am looking for some help.

Let $f(x)=C$ be a constant function on the interval $[a,b]$; and let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$.

I need to calculate $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$

So I know that a partition of $[a,b]$ is an ordered set of points $P=\{x_0,...x_n\}$ such that $a=x_0<x_1<....<x_{n-1}<x_n=b$

But how do I find $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$

isn't $$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\inf_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

and $$U(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\sup_{x\in[x_{i-1},x_i]}f(x)\right)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$

So my question is how do I calculate $L(f,P)$ and $U(f,P)$?

Comment: What don't you understand? The calculation is trivial because $f$ is constant. As a result, the infimum and supremum over each subinterval is just the constant $c$, and both your sums telescope, giving $c(b-a)$.

Comment: Please read the tag description for proof-verification. You will see that it doesn't apply. Your definitions of lower sum and upper sum are correct. Now you need to calculate the infimum and supremum of $f$ on those intervals. That should be easy.

Comment: how do I show that?

Comment: @jh123 what is the infimum, in any subinterval, of a constant function? And the supremum?

Comment: c(b-a)?????????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f\left( [a, \,b] \right) = \{C\}$

$\sup \,\{C\}=C$

$\inf \,\{C\}=C$

Notice we have
\begin{align}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - x_{i-1}) &= (x_1 - x_0) + (x_2 - x_1) + (x_3 - x_2) + \cdots + (x_n - x_{n-1})
\\&=(x_n-x_0)+(x_1 - x_1)+(x_2 - x_2)+(x_3-x_3)+\cdots+(x_{n-1} - x_{n-1})
\\&=(b-a)\,.
\end{align}

Don't bog yourself down by worrying too much. It seems like there isn't much to show here because there is not.

Comment: thanks for showing how that is telescoping

Comment: so then $$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\Delta x_i = c(b-a)=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\Delta x_i=U(f,P)$$??

Comment: @jh123 what do you think? $L(f,P)=U(f,P)$ is true or not? You knows what is $m_i$ and $M_i$?

Comment: well yes since sup,inf=C and the sum of $x_i$ is $b-a$

Comment: Yes because as Itay4 notes
$M_i=C$ and $m_i=C$.

I upvoted Itay4's answer because it is equally both valid and insightful.

Comment: thanks I will use a combonation of both since your shows nicely how the sum is telescoping

Comment: Believe it or not, James Stewart actually has some decent ideas for convincing ways to write Real Analysis. I am forever grateful that people insisted I learn Calculus from the guy in undergrad.

Answer (score 2):

As $f$ is constant, $\sup_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)=c$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta x_i=b-a$, we get:

$$L(f,P)=\sum_{i=1}^nm_i\Delta x_i = c(b-a)=\sum_{i=1}^nM_i\Delta x_i=U(f,P)$$

Comment: does this calculate the inf and sup of f on my partition?

Comment: @jh123 Yes, this works for every partition.

Comment: Strictly speaking you should say that for any $[p,q] \subset [a,b]$ the sup and inf are both $c$, otherwise you are omitting a (simple, admittedly) step.

Comment: how did you get the inf and sup to be c(b-a)?

Comment: could that be edited into the answer? then I will accept it

Comment: The supremum and the infimum are not $c(b-a)$, but $c$. The sum of $\Delta x_i$ is $(b-a)$.

Comment: okay I understand what you mean, could you include that sum calculation in the answer'

Comment: @Itay4 last question thanks for your help, why is the sum (b-a) could you explain that?

Comment: @jh123 Well, that stands for every sum of every partition. Remember that we are summing up $n$ sub-intervals of $[a,b]$. We will end up getting the whole interval, by getting a telescoping sum.